# Succinct way of modifying/erasing entries while iterating unordered_map?

Tags: c++

I wanted to do something like this:

```
unordered_map<string, deque<string>> table;

...
...

for (const auto &key_deque_pair : table) {
    string key = key_deque_pair.first;
    deque<string> &value_deque = key_deque_pair.second;
    if (value_deque.back() == "NULL") {
        //erase key
        table.erase(key);
    } else {
        //modify value
        swap(value_deque[0], value_deque.back());
        value_deque.resize(1);
    }
}
```

Then I learned this can lead to an undefined behavior because modifying/erasing while iterating corrupts the iterator.

I think the following code achieves the desired result without this error, in the `//erase key` case.

```
auto it = table.begin();
while(it != table.end()) {
    string key = it->first;
    deque<string> &value_deque = it->second;
    if (value_deque.back() == "NULL") {
        //erase key
        it = table.erase(it);
    } else {
        //modify value
        swap(value_deque[0], value_deque.back());
        value_deque.resize(1);
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Is the `//modify value` case also correct, or should I erase the entry using `it` and then put the modified value with that key?

Also, is there any way to do this using `for ... each`, or in a succinct form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to delete from a container while iterating thru it.  Your `//modify value` case is correct.  There is no way to safely remove from a container using `for...each` style.

Comment: Not only *remove* but also *add*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You mean even adding an element while iterating is not safe?

Comment: It depends on the container.  Some containers (like list) don't invalidate iterators when adding; others (like vector, when it needs to reallocate memory) might.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the `//modify value` case also correct, or should I erase the entry using it and then put the modified value with that key?

It's correct as is - you can freely modify values (but not keys).  You might consider this though...

```
value_deque[0] = std::move(value_deque.back());
```

...IMHO, it's a clearer expression of what you want done.

> Also, is there any way to do this using for ... each, or in a succinct form?

Only thing I can suggest is that you'd cut a line and limit `it` to the ostensibly needed scope if you used a `for` statement (i.e. `for (auto it = table.begin(); it != table.end(); ) ...`

Comment: You don't want to `++it` in the for loop since you're modifying it when you erase from table.

Comment: I don't think `value_deque[0] = std::move(value_deque.back());` does the same modify operation I want to do. My program moves the last element of the deque the only element. e.g. `[A, B, C, D] -> [D]`, whereas your suggestion somehow transforms it to `[D, C, B, A]`.

Comment: @user2418202: you go from `[A, B, C, D]` to `[D, B, C, A]` to `[D]`.  My suggestion was to go from `[A, B, C, D]` to `[D, B, C, unspecified-but-value]` to `[D]`, in other words, `=`/`move` is an alternative to `swap`, but you still need to `resize`.  Not sure how you thought it yielded `[D, C, B, A]`...?

Comment: @TonyD Oh you mean with `resize`. I see. It's strange why it printed [D, C, B, A].