# Loop on newly added elements of std::unorderd_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

During a loop on an `std::unordered_map` I need in some cases to add a new element to the map:

```
for (auto &element : map) {
  if (condition) {
    map.insert(newElement);
  }
  // Do something with element
}
```

It happens that `newElement` might be inserted before `element`, so that it is not processed by the loop. How can I modify the code so that all of the eventually added elements are processed by the loop?

Comment: Don't modify the container you're iterating over, that leads to headaches and problems.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599579/succinct-way-of-modifying-erasing-entries-while-iterating-unordered-map

Comment: Inserting while iterating over an unordered map is flat out undefined behavior. If the map has to grow, [all iterators are invalidated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert).

Comment: what is it that you are actually doing? Do you really need the newly inserted element be handled by an iteration when it comes after the current element but not be processed when it comes before the current element? In an `unordered_map`? That doesn't sound right

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I think I'll add the new element to another map, operate on them, and then transfer them to the original map.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Rather than only asking about the code to solve some problem you should tell us about the actual problem this code is supposed to solve. Inserting elements into the map invalidates iterators, hence fixing your code requires to consider what and why it actually does

Comment: "I think I'll add the new element to another map, operate on them, and then transfer them to the original map." what I was going to propose, but then you wont know if the element come before or after